# How to measure load detection for ballast output 18W

Tags: circuit-design, load, detection, electronic-ballast, current-sensor

I have a high performance ballast of only 18 and 36 W. I would like to do a detection circuit whenever the UV light tube does not have any light out, an alarm/signal can be triggered to replace the light tube to connect to the ballast.

The one i could think of is current sensing using hall effect sensor ACS712-5A. By theory, whenever the tube is not working, I think there shall be no current flow.
However, the current is too small and the signal is in AC and it is very hard to get a read on the sensor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdmLdK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there any way for detect such application?
Either we need to measure current or using any other solution?

Comment: A circuit diragram would help to understand your problem. What has "the UV light tube" to do with the problem?

Comment: I have edited to include a simple diagram as shown. UV Light / Fluorescent light tube would be the load of the ballast.

Comment: You could use a photosensor of some sort to sense the light directly as well.  Would have to be outside the ballast of course.  You say you "have" the ballast.  Do you mean you're designing a ballast, or you have one with which you're wiring a fixture?

Comment: I have the one which i am wiring a fixture. Do not design the ballast.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: [CR3110-3000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cr-magnetics-inc/CR3110-3000/1045160?utm_adgroup=Current%20Sense%20Transformers&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Transformers&utm_term=&utm_content=Current%20Sense%20Transformers&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoab_BRCxARIsANMx4S7i1S7Yf7sQ_Hh_ZzMdXw58MqlCbgufs7otQ6LRNGSoliK4WOFMLhAaApRzEALw_wcB)

This is just 16$ but the catch is the output of this sensor is in AC as well. So to read it via ADC, you need to rectify it. I used half-wave rectification (Diode and cap). They barely add to the cost.

Comment: Operating frequency according to question: 44 kHz. "Sensor" frequency range: up to 1 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

If the current is AC, you can use a current transformer.

These comes in different sensitivity to measure different range of current range like the [CR4110-0.5](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cr-magnetics-inc/CR4110-0.5/582-1086-ND/2485719) which has a rating of 500mA which should be good enough to measure down to the mA range.

If that's not enough, you can make the wire pass several time in it to increase the sensitivity.

EDIT:

Just saw the 44kHz frequency range, that is beyond what most sensor will be able to handle, but you can just place it before the ballast on the 220AC lines, it will work the same, you just need to check what is the delta V when tubes / no tubes.

Comment: the CT as the recommended is quite pricey. Is it ok if this type of [CT](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1790368.pdf?_ga=2.110938821.198478037.1551348282-2146794224.1502413941&_gac=1.158375496.1551436361.Cj0KCQiAzePjBRCRARIsAGkrSm5Fe2zz3vUZxQOCLYvnvvVNi75AoSaFEFldgeEqbH1_HiY6JcSGu1kaAn8_EALw_wcB) is used ? Sorry to ask this, but what is the meaning of delta V ?

Comment: you can probably find cheaper ones, or even build your own, you only need a winding with empty core, a bridge rectifier a cap and load resistor. Basically works the same way as a transformer and the power cable is your primary. By delta V i mean the sensor output value difference when the tube is on or broken.

Comment: well, how to build a winding with empty core ? sorry as dont have any experience in this. Just to make sure, the delta voltage is to check after the rectifier voltage ?

Comment: you can use something like this and make the cable pass in the middle, once or several times if the signal isn't enough https://www.google.com/shopping/product/15542544997855978792?biw=1370&bih=775&q=coil+empty+air+inductor&oq=coil+empty+air+inductor&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj209-WgeHgAhVGX60KHcJLDP4QrhIITg

Comment: it would not be used as a inductor anymore but as a transformer secondary. small hack.

Comment: oh. would the secondary winding number of turns would also have different voltage as well ?

Comment: Note that a current transformer transforms current, and must *never* be presented with a significant impedance on the secondary while operating, as it will produce any voltage necessary to overcome that impedance.  Be sure to read up on and fully understand before installing/using one.